# Using Lets-Encrypt SSL cert with Jetty

Tags: ssl, jetty, lets-encrypt

Has anyone been successful with using Letsencrypt SSL with a default jetty install? I can't seem to get it right.

More info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Jetty Path: /opt/jetty
```

Only thing adjusted is enabling http on port 80 in start.ini.

Problems I have run into:

When I input --module-ssl into the start ini, I get the error

> No default protocol for ServerConnector@48aca48b{null,[]}{0.0.0.0:8443}`

starting jetty and it fails.

I have tried inputting the SSL info into the ini, as well as editing the .xml files with the info.

Comment: You should include information on what kind of problems you've run into. Are you seeing any error messages? What have you already done?

Comment: @JamesKraus Thanks i have updated it, Jetty is fairly new to me so i have tried to provide as much info as possible

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an older question, but in-case people stumble across it on Google with a similar issue:

The SSL module in Jetty is just the base cryptographic functionality. You need to *do something* with it - i.e. also enable the `https` or `http2` modules.

In other words, for standard https you actually need:

```
java -jar start.jar --add-to-startd=ssl,https
```

So it's not the best of error messages, but:

> No default protocol for ServerConnector

Means just that - it didn't previously have a protocol (implementation) to use the ssl module with, because the `https` (or `http2`) modules hadn't been loaded.